# Akka Scheduler resets logger levels. Why?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework-2.0, akka, logback

Global.scala in a new Play2 application:

```
import play.api.{GlobalSettings, Application}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.Play
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import play.api.Logger

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  val logger = Logger("foo")

  // `printLoggerLevels` prints logger levels
  def printLoggerLevels(prepend:String) =
    logger.error(
      prepend +": "+
      logger.isErrorEnabled +" "+
      logger.isWarnEnabled +" "+
      logger.isInfoEnabled +" "+
      logger.isDebugEnabled +" "+
      logger.isTraceEnabled
    )

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    printLoggerLevels("outside scheduleOnce")
    Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(500 milliseconds) {
      printLoggerLevels("inside scheduleOnce")
    } 
  } 
}
```

This prints logger levels outside and inside a `Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(500 milliseconds) {...}` like so:

```
$ play start 9000
[error] foo - outside scheduleOnce: true true true true false <----- notice this
[info] play - Starting application default Akka system.
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jEventHandler - Slf4jEventHandler started
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[error] foo - inside scheduleOnce: true false false false false  <----- and this
```

Above you can see, that logger levels inside `scheduleOnce` are reset to ERROR. Outside `scheduleOnce` they're on DEBUG and inside they're on ERROR. If I were to run it with `play run` it would run fine, and the levels would be the same, but when starting with `play start`, they get reset.

Application.conf:

```
logger.root=DEBUG
logger.play=INFO
logger.application=INFO
```

This is a fresh project, I haven't made any changes I didn't post.

Why does this happen?

Edit: Another way to ask this question would be: how does running an application with `start` affect it's inner workings, and in turn, how does that affect logging levels within anonymous function passed to Akka's scheduler?

Edit: Play version is 2.1.4

Comment: Could you be more specific about the version? Is this Play 2.0.0? There have been some pretty big changes between the v2 releases in terms of how projects are built etc...

Comment: @torbinsky my exact Play version is 2.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a mess to be honest. It has improved in Play 2.2.x, but it's still messy.

The big difference between run and start here is that in run, the Netty server is started before the application is loaded (because it doesn't load the application until you first hit the netty server, because it's dynamic).  In start, the netty server is started after the application is loaded, because you don't want to start serving requests until you have an application that can serve them.  It's when the netty server is started that the logger gets configured.